# How to grave the Date from this command in bash script

Tags: bash

```
!/bin/bash

# When a match is not found, just present nothing.
shopt -s nullglob

# Match all .wav files containing the date format.
files=(*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.wav)

if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
echo "No match found."
fi

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
# We get the date part by part
file_date=''
# Sleep it to parts.
IFS="-." read -ra parts <<< "$file"
for t in "${parts[@]}"; do
        # Break from the loop if a match is found
    if [[ $t == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
        file_date=$t
        break
    fi
done
# If a value was not assigned, then show an error message and continue to the next file.
# Just making sure there is nothing in Array and date before it moves on
if [[ -z $file_date ]]; then

    continue
fi

file_year=${file_date:0:4}
file_month=${file_date:4:2}




mkdir -p "$file_year/$file_month"

# -- is just there to not interpret filenames starting with - as options.

echo "Moving: ./"$file "to: " "./"$file_year"/"$file_month
mv  "$file" "$file_year/$file_month"
done
```

Now there are files I would need to do the date to gra the date and then move it like I do now. for example there is a file called meetme.. its a wav file and I have DIR with YYYY/MM and would like to move thoses files without YYYYMMDD in file name already

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing a program to do something with that information, then you might prefer seconds-since-epoch and use `date` to get the date in the desired format.

```
$ date -d @$(stat --format='%Y' testdisk.log) +%Y%m%d
20130422
```

You can also get the ascii representation, and then [manipulate the string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

```
$ stat --format='%y' testdisk.log 
2013-04-22 09:11:39.000000000 -0500
$ date_st=$(stat --format='%y' testdisk.log)
$ date_st=${date_st/ */}
$ date_st=${date_st//-/}
$ echo ${date_st}
20130422
```

Comment: Modified your first example to get the date from the timestamp.

Comment: If I do $ date -d @$(stat --format='%Y' testdisk.log) +%Y%m%d
20131007 how do I store that in an array.. I have this right now I edit my code cause I have it sorting files already with YYYYMMDD and I wanna keep it like that hen when a file comes in with out YYYYMMDD do the date command and then move the file